# Error: Could not find or load main class Adventure Game

Tags: java, windows

I'm working on something for class and keep getting this same error. I'm aware it has been answered before but no other thread has helped me successfully. Please forgive improper formatting/tagging as this is my first time on this website.

This is my code:

```
    //imports
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

//this is where class info goes
class Adventure {
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {}

public class Game {
//setting characteristics for the story
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner enterScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int playerHP;
String playerName;
String playerWeapon;
int choice;
int dragonHP;

int goldKey;

public void main(String[] args) {

    Game dublin;
    dublin = new Game();

    dublin.playerSetUp();     
    dublin.stoneGate();
}

public void playerSetUp(){


    playerHP = 15;
    dragonHP = 20;

    playerWeapon = "Stick";

    System.out.println("Health: "+ playerHP);
    System.out.println("Weapon: "+ playerWeapon);
//the story's intro
    System.out.println("You wake up in an unfamiliar clearing, unable to remember what you are doing.");
    System.out.println("You survey the area but are sure you've never been here before.");
    System.out.println("A name seems to be bubbling up in your consciousness.");
    System.out.println("You think it is...");
//this is where they input their name
    playerName = myScanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Right! " + playerName + "! That's your name!");    


}    

public void stoneGate(){

        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("You wander over to a large stone wall gate ahead of you.");
    System.out.println("It appears to be secured with a gold lock.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You decide the best thing to do is...");
    System.out.println("");
    //choice options
    System.out.println("1: Attempt to unlock the gate.");
    System.out.println("2: Kick the gate.");
    System.out.println("3: Walk away for now.");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

    choice = myScanner.nextInt();

    if(choice==1){
        if(goldKey==1){
            ending();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You pull at the lock but it will not budge. Seems like you'll have to try something else.");
            enterScanner.nextLine();
            stoneGate();
        }

    }
    else if(choice==2){
        playerHP = playerHP-1;
        System.out.println("You try kicking the gate down. \n\n Your kick dislodged some stones from above that fall and hit you. \n(You receive 1 damage)\n");
        System.out.println("Health: " + playerHP);
        enterScanner.nextLine();
        stoneGate();
    }
    else if(choice==3){
        fourRoads();
    }    
    else{
        stoneGate();
    }
}

public void fourRoads(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("You wind up at a four way intersection. If you go south, you return to the gate. \n\n");
    System.out.println("1: Go north.");
    System.out.println("2: Go east.");
    System.out.println("3: Go west.");
    System.out.println("4: Go back.");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

    choice = myScanner.nextInt();

    if(choice==1){
        north();
    }
    else if(choice==2){
        east();
    }
    else if(choice==3){
        west();
    }
    else if(choice==4){
        stoneGate();
    }
    else{
        fourRoads();
    }
}
//option 1
public void north(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("You find a waterfall! The soothing sounds of the water make you feel refreshed.");
    System.out.println("You rest by the water and recover some health.");
    playerHP = playerHP + 1;
    System.out.println("Health: " + playerHP);
    System.out.println("\n\n1: Go back to the intersection");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

    choice = myScanner.nextInt();

    if(choice==1){
        fourRoads();
    }
    else{
        north();
    }
}
//option 2
public void east(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("You discover a treasure chest inside a small cave.");
    System.out.println("You open it and discover a sword!");
    playerWeapon = "Sword";
    System.out.println("Your Weapon: "+ playerWeapon);
    System.out.println("\n\n1: Go back to the intersection");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

    choice = myScanner.nextInt();

    if(choice==1){
        fourRoads();
    }
    else{
        north();
    }
}
//option 3
public void west(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("You stumble upon a sleeping dragon!\n");
    System.out.println("It wakes up as you approach.\n");
    System.out.println("It looks angry!! You decide it’s a good idea to...\n");
    System.out.println("1: Try to fight it!");
    System.out.println("2: Run away!");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

    choice = myScanner.nextInt();

    if(choice==1){
        fight();
    }
    else if(choice==2){
        fourRoads();
    }
    else{
        west();
    }
}

public void fight(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("Health: "+ playerHP);
    System.out.println("Dragon Health: " + dragonHP);
    System.out.println("\n1: Attack!");
    System.out.println("2: Run!");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

    choice = myScanner.nextInt();

    if(choice==1){
        attack();
    }
    else if(choice==2){
        fourRoads();
    }
    else{
        fight();
    }
}

public void attack(){
    int playerDamage =0;

//stick is basically garenteed game over
    if(playerWeapon.equals("Stick")){
        playerDamage = new java.util.Random().nextInt(3); 
    }
    else if(playerWeapon.equals("Sword")){
        playerDamage = new java.util.Random().nextInt(8); 
    }

    System.out.println("You swing at the dragon and give " + playerDamage + " damage!");

    dragonHP = dragonHP - playerDamage;

    System.out.println("dragon HP: " + dragonHP);

    if(dragonHP<1){
        win();
    }
    else if(dragonHP>0){
        int dragonDamage =0;

        dragonDamage = new java.util.Random().nextInt(4);

        System.out.println("The dragon attacks and gives you " + dragonDamage + " damage!");

        playerHP = playerHP - dragonDamage;

        System.out.println("Health: " + playerHP);

        if(playerHP<1){
            dead();
        }
        else if(playerHP>0){
            fight();
        }
    }


}
//game over
public void dead(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("You were slain by the dragon!");
    System.out.println("\n\nGAME OVER");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

}

public void win(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("The dragon runs away before it gets further injured.");
    System.out.println("In its hurry it drops something.");
    System.out.println("You walk over and discover a gold key!\n\n");
    System.out.println("You can use this on the gate!");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");

    goldKey = 1;

    choice = myScanner.nextInt();
    if(choice==1){
        fourRoads();
    }
    else{
        win();
    }

}
//ending
public void ending(){
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
    System.out.println("You use the key to unlock the gate.");
    System.out.println("The moment you step foot inside...");
    System.out.println("You wake up in your own bed to your mom calling‘" + playerName +" it’s time for school!!’");
    System.out.println("It was all a dream!");
    System.out.println("\n\n           ~THE END~                   ");
        System.out.println("\n_______________________________________\n");
}
}
}
```

Please don't mind how messy this is, I'm mostly concerned with it launching. I put it into several online compilers/executors before and they all indicated it was successful but I keep getting this error when trying to run it via command prompt. When attempting to run it I change my cmd directory to the directory the file is in and input "java Filename.java" which appears to work except for this.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: You have 2 `public void main(String[] args)`

Comment: A `main` method needs to be `static`, in order to be interpreted as a point of entry for your program. This is not the case for the one in your `Game` class.

Comment: Hint: mess does matter. First of all you are not doing yourself a favor with messy code. Messy code attracts bugs like shiny lights attract bugs in summer evenings.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your main method is empty so nothing will happen.
2) You have two methods called `main`.

Comment: Any insight as to how I should fix things?

Comment: You coul rename your `main` in Game and call it from your main in Adventure: `public static void main(String[] args){ Game game = new Game(); game.yourRenamedMethod(args);}`

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite slow, how would you suggest I rename the 'main' in Game?

Comment: Just put `public void yourName(String[] args){` for the method header.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method should be:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {}
```

What I mean by this is: the code that is inside your `public void main(String[] args)` should be in the `static` main method, or you can just call this main method inside the `static` main

In order to fix this, just do the following:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
   Game dublin;
   dublin = new Game();

   dublin.playerSetUp();     
   dublin.stoneGate();
}
```

And delete your other method where you had this piece of code.

Comment: How would you suggest I fix this? I'm quite slow at this so I apologize for not being able to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I seem to get an error on the fact that "new" in "new Game" is nonstatic and is coming from static context?

Comment: All methods that will be called inside this new main method, should be static. Just write static in the head of your methods, before the type (including your class head).

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods named `main`